# Early 2011 MBP has odd dots on external monitor

Tags: display, error

I have this Mac:

[image: About my Mac]

And it's attached to an Acer P191w. It will show an odd grid of dots on the external monitor like so:

[image: Odd dots]

When I move the application the dots will get 'refreshed' and go away (they're not stuck pixels) but will quickly 'refill' themselves in 5-10 seconds. The app they're on there is Sublime Text 2, but it occurs on any app. I just put it up for contrast. I don't appear to get the dots on my laptop display, just the external.

I have checked the wire connecting the two, it appears tight and secure.

Occasionally this will prelude a full lockup of the machine forcing a hard reboot.

I'd appreciate any insight into this matter.

Comment: Have you tried a different external display to see if the issue persists?

Comment: Alas, I only have one external display :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [discussion thread on forums.macrumors.com](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1004335) says this can be fixed by unplugging and replugging all of the video connections.

Comment: I added the link, but it doesn't provide much additional info.

Answer (score 2):

If you can see it in a screenshot, it's likely something with the video signal being sent from the GPU. This could be a problem with the GPU itself or some kind of weird software issue. The best way to tell is to try booting to an external OS like your recovery partition or an OS on an external hard drive to see if it occurs there as well. If it does, it's probably an issue with the GPU. If not, try a reinstall. If you don't have these resources on hand, take a trip to your local Apple Store to have them test it out for you.

A couple other quick fixes you could try that may or may not work are:

1. Restting the PRAM (see [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) guide)
2. Recalibrating the display. (see [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2805) guide)